# GFCI No Equipment Ground not testing

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci

A GFCI installed near a sink has this sticker on it. From what I gather online, this means the outlet was installed on place of an old 2 wire outlet, and it's safe anyway, and up to code. But it's not shutting off when I press the test button. Is that normal for an ungrounded GFCI? Is it supposed to test with the button even when no equipment is grounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When equipment ground is not present, GFCI devices should test properly.

However, if equipment ground is not present, external GFCI testers there or at downline outlets  *should not* test successfully.  Their built-in 3-lamp tester should only display one yellow light.  If it displays two *but doesn't trip the GFCI*, that means a bootleg ground, which makes the GFCI's protection worthless.